# Interpreting NoSuchMethod error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following error in my rails application when I click on a link

```
<%= link_to 'Add New Slinky', new_admin_slinky_path %>
```

Here is the error:

```
NoMethodError in Admin/slinkys#new
Showing /Users/Me/Folder/Folder/app/views/admin/slinkys/new.html.erb where line #7 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
Extracted source (around line #7):

4: <h5>Here is a header</h5>
5: <li>Here is a bullet</li>
6: <br>
7: <%= simple_form_for @slinky_file do |f| %>
8: <%= f.file_field :file %>
9: <br>
10: <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
```

What does this error mean? What is wrong with line 7?

Comment: That's more like html

Comment: its means that whats in @slinky_file is nil. Check your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this mean that @slinky_file == nil, you have to set it before use

upd:

in controller like

```
@slinky_file = SlinkyFile.find(params[:slinky_file])
```

or, if you want to init new model instance

```
@slinky_file = SlinkyFile.new
```